# Using OpenGLES 2.0 in a cocos application

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader

Is there a way to use OpenGLES 2.0 in a cocos application?

Reading about it on the cocos2d website I read mentions of 2.0 support coming after cocos2d 1.0 (before if it's not too hard), but I cannot find any information about the progress of it.

I would like to apply some shader effect on some CCNodes. Any pointers as to how to do it, even in a really hacked version? Is it possible to mix OpenGLES 1.0 and 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to mix opengl es 1.0 and 2.0. In 2.0 essential render steps are done with shaders and the 1.0 functions don't work in 2.0 gl view.

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo Quesada the main developer on Cocos2D has branch setup for OGL 2.0 dev work...

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tree/gles20

I believe he has gotten a bunch of shaders working already but its not necessarily ready for prime time just yet.  There is also some discussions in the Cocos2D forums going on about this...

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/tags/opengl-es-20